# PostgreSql "running post install step…the Database Cluster Initialisation failed"

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm a Windows user - it took me a couple of hours of constant installs and uninstalls before I could get this working, with the first 10 or so times coming to see the error message in the title.

I place this here as a self-answered question to prevent others who might run into the same problem while installing, and include some basic usage methods for those like me who are first comers in using PostgreSql.

Comment: In my case it was a registry key issue, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68737037/16638409

Answer (score 26):

You have to mannualy run initdb which is present : "C:\Software\PostgreSql\12\bin"

Now make sure u associate "postgres" as user alongwith the initdb cmd since "postgres" is the superuser that got created during installation.

```
initdb -U postgres -D "D:\PostgreSql\12\data"
```

Now once database cluster is initialized then you can start the server by using pg_ctl utility present inside bin folder of PostgreSql\12

```
pg_ctl start -D "D:\PostgreSql\12\data"
```

Or you can also register it as a windows service and you can set it to automatic

```
pg_ctl register -N PostgreSql-12.3.1 -D "D:\PostgreSql\12\data"
```

Now you are all set to use the postgresql database.
Either use it through cmd line (psql) or pgAdmin4

Comment: to run the `pg_ctl register` command, you will need to be using cmd prompt as an admin.

Comment: Add the initdb command can only be run as as a non-admin.

Answer (score 16):

I faced some major issues with this myself when trying to install PostgreSQL 9.6 and couldn't get it working despite the above answers. What solved it for me was either

### In the installer

When prompted for locale, do not check 'default locale'. Instead, choose something like 'United States English'. For some reason, the default doesn't work.

### After the installer

If you went ahead and checked 'default locale' anyways, you can still fix the installation errors without reinstalling the whole thing. What you need to do is similar to above answers, but with slight changes:

1. Go to your postgres /bin directory (default location: `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin"`) and execute the following query:

`initdb -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data" -U postgres --locale="English_United States.1252"`

As you can see, locale is not an intuitive string such as "en_US.UTF8", so this can get quite nasty if you don't know what is going on. Anyways, the above code should result in a "Success" message.

2. Next, execute the following command:

`pg_ctl register -N PostgreSQL -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data"`

This should result in a windows service called PostgreSQL.

3. Lastly, to start your newly created service, enter:

`net start PostgreSQL`

That's it. everything should be up and running now.

Comment: I did the step by step with version 14 and it worked.

Comment: Windows 11 (64bit), Postgres 15. I had an error on step 1):



`fixing permissions on existing directory c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/data ... initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/data": Permission denied`



To resolve this I had to give "Everyone" access to the data folder first, then the command succeeded.

The rest of the steps also worked as expected.

Comment: Worked on PostgreSQL 16.1

Answer (score 2):

**Installation**)

- Download the appropriate install file for your system.
- Make sure to install to the default path:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\` was the default on my system.

Not installing to the default path may give you dll errors and whatnot.

If installation completed with no problem,

PostgreSql would have created a database with the user `postgres` and the password being the value you inputted during installation.

- Add the `PostgreSQL\9.3\bin` folder to your PATH.

**PostgreSql usage**)

What's important in now using PostgreSql is this:

login is as user **postgres** for whatever command you want to use.

Ignoring this will give you constant `password authentication failed` messages, since you'll be attempting to login as your PC's ID.

**For example**)

- logging into psql)

`psql -U postgres`

- creating a new database)

`createdb -U postgres [dbname] [etc...]`

- executing a sql data file (ex. data.sql) within a certain database)

`psql -U postgres -f data.sql dbname`

**Additional Usage**

Once logged into psql (through `psql -U postgres`), you can use the following commands

- `\l` list the available databases
- `\c [dbname]` 'connect' to a database
- `\d` display the description of that database (once connected)

I hope this helps.

I'll add some more examples if I run into any more problems during my first couple of days  of usage.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem during installation. What worked for me was to uninstall Postgres and the run the .exe file as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, Firstly uninstall any instances of postgres.

Afterwards do the following steps,

1. Open the run command using win + r -> search for compmgmt.msc
2. Select Local Users and Group.
3. Add new user as postgres and set password as root
4. After creating user:postgres click on the users folder , select postgres user.
5. In the memberOf tab click on the add button in the bottom left corner, A dialog box appears inside the **"Enter the object names to select"** section type Administrators
6. Click ok and finish
7. click on the postgres user again and in the general tab, Uncheck **user must change password at next logon** box.
8. copy the postgres installation file to c:/
9. open cmd run this command **"runas /user:postgres cmd.exe"**.
10. new cmd opens with user as postgres provide your password.
11. navigate to cd /
12. now enter the full name of the installation file in the root folder.

Afterwards , the installation will take place normally without any error.

This worked for me, Try it yourself if it works for you or not.