# Can not run PostgreSQL by pg_ctl

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm new in PostgreSQL, every thing worked fine until unexpected restart, now when I trying to run postgres by this command

`>pg_ctl.exe start`

it says :

> The program "postgres" was found by "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin/pg_ctl.exe"
> but was not the same version as pg_ctl.
> Check your installation.

the version of postgres and pg_ctl.exe are same (both of them : 13.1)

[command line image]

[image: 1]

I've tried another way, I try to run postgres service in windows services it run and stopped immediately
and shows a warning
[warning image]

[image: 2]

so I checked logs(in windows event viewer)and it said :

> FATAL: XX000: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\postgres.exe: could not locate matching postgres executable LOCATION: getInstallationPaths, d:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\postmaster\postmaster.c:1489

OS : windows server 2019

PostgreSQL Version : 13

Comment: Please don't post images. Copy and paste the text into your question.  Where did you get Postgres from and how did you install it?

Comment: What does `where pg_ctl` give you? Did you try specifying the full path to the executable? But more importantly, you have to specify a data directory, otherwise `pg_ctl` will never be able to start Postgres.

Comment: sorry I'm newbie in stackoverflow, I [get from here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) and used windows installer @AdrianKlaver

Comment: `where pg_ctl` give me `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_ctl.exe` , I've set PGDATA = "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data" @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 14):

In my case I tried all the solutions I found online. None worked. Dozens of reinstall tries.

Then I remembered that I changed one parameter in the registry to better display the local language in cmd.

Returning the value of the command line encoding registry value solved the problem in my case.

Change your registry value to empty:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun`

Comment: But this was suggested for psql to have utf-8.
Why doesn't this run now?

Comment: I faced the same issue in psql 14. Your solution resolved my issue

Comment: Thank you so much, Anton. It worked for me too. I've been searching for a solution for like last 1.5 hours and none of them worked so far. My problem was exactly what you said, I had some custom DOSKEY commands and I did put the file's path as a value for AutoRun registry key.

Comment: Glad to see solution helped.

Answer (score -1):

#### Please choose the solution that suits your problem.

> The following errors do not necessarily appear on your computer, but this increases the probability of fixing them.

1. Using American English if psql is going to localize on the current computer.
2. If you try to install psql on a non-default path using Windows, do not place it outside disk C.
3. In the last step of the installation, add the `postgres` user and give it all permissions in the installation path location, which is especially important for initial writes to the data directory.

> A good and simple example is to run `net user /add` so that you can use psql right away.

4. Do not run default things similar to `poshrc` in *Computer\ HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ Software\ Microsoft\ Command Processor\ Autorun*, transfer and move to **HKCU**!

- If none of the above methods work, at least we can start it manually by running the following command

```
.\<Path to PostgreSQL>\<version>\bin\initdb -D "<Path to PostgreSQL>\<version>\data"
.\<Path to PostgreSQL>\<version>\bin\pg_ctl start -D "<Path to PostgreSQL>\<version>\data"
```