PostgreSQL Download Problem Data Folder Empty
enter image description hereI'm trying to download postgresql on my computer but I couldn't because of the data folder. I took that(The database cluster initialisation failed.) error during download process and my data folder is empty. I've tried to run init_db file as manually. But I took 0xC0000409 exception error. I couldn't solve my problems. Can you help me?
I will use postgresql for my spring boot project.

Selam Amine,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63778894/17052702
The "In the installer" part of this answer helped me to solve the exact problem you have. I got the same error as you and 'data' folder in my PostgreSQL location was empty. I just uninstalled it and installed again with selecting "English, United States" instead of "default locale" and it is working as expected now.
